# Changing Columns names instead of from schema

Tags: c#

I am using the following code I found to create a csv which while it works I am wanting to name the column names would anyone have any idea how I would go about.

```
public void DumpTableToFile(SqlConnection connection, string tableName, string destinationFile)
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("select * from " + tableName, connection))
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        using (var outFile = File.CreateText(destinationFile))
        {
            string[] columnNames = GetColumnNames(reader).ToArray();
            int numFields = columnNames.Length;
            outFile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string[] columnValues =
                        Enumerable.Range(0, numFields)
                                  .Select(i => reader.GetValue(i).ToString())
                                  .Select(field => string.Concat("\"", field.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""))
                                  .ToArray();
                    outFile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnValues));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> GetColumnNames(IDataReader reader)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
        {
            yield return (string)row["ColumnName"];
        }
    }
```

I supsect I could do an if statement here and transpose them. But was wondering if somone had a better idea.

Comment: You subject mentions transpose and the text talks about adding header rows, can you clarify what you are aiming to do?

Comment: Why don't fill `columnNames` with values you need, instead retrieving them from data reader?

Comment: @Dennis cause the table has other columns in it as well that I dont want to change its just certain ones could you clarify with some example code in an answer

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft i changed the title instead

Comment: Just replace the ones you want to change in the column names array. columnNames[<index or name>] = "MyNewColumnName";

Comment: I would probably done `while(reader.HasRows) { reader.Read(); // rest of code }`

Comment: It also appears that `SqlDataReader` which is what `command.ExecuteReader` returns is `IEnumerable` which means you can do `foreach(var dataRow in reader)`. Unless, you want to do this asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *extracting a method* first for plain String to csv, second to sql query:

```
private static String ToCsv(String value) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return "";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

  bool hasSpecial = false; 

  foreach (var ch in value) {
    if ((ch == ',') || (ch == '\\') || (ch == '"')) {
      hasSpecial = true;

      sb.Append('\\'); 
    }

    sb.Append(ch);
  }

  if (hasSpecial) {
    sb.Insert(0, '"');
    sb.Append('"');
  } 

  return sb.ToString();
}

private static IEnumerable<String> TableToCsv(SqlConnection connection, 
                                              string tableName, 
                                              bool colummNames = true) {
  //TODO: simplest, but prone to SQL injection solution; tableName should be validated 
  String sql = String.Format("select * from {0}", tableName);

  using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
      // Let's take columns' names from query
      if (colummNames)
        yield return String.Join(",", Enumerable
          .Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
          .Select(i => ToCsv(reader.GetName(i))));

      while (reader.Read())
        yield return String.Join(",", Enumerable
          .Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
          .Select(i => ToCsv(reader.GetFieldValue<String>(i))));
  }
}
```

And then use it:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.csv",
  TableToCsv(myConnection, "MyTable", true));
```

Comment: Thank you that worked very well and on me dummy data to

Comment: @david: You're welcome! Next time, try to decompose difficult problem into smaller methods (plain string to csv one, obtaining column names, converting table's body etc.)